# get tabs based on select box value

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

i have a select box with values 1 to 5 and if i select value 2 from select box i should get 2 tabs or 3 i should get 3 tabs..

here is select box code..

```
<select id="Week" name="Week">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

how can i do it in php, javascript or jquery.

help me out
uday

Comment: What you mean by "i should get 2 tabs or 3 i should get 3 tabs"

Comment: Hi Mihai..week1 week2 week3 week4 week5 if i click week1 tab i will get some data or if get week2 i will get some data..like this

Comment: Hi yahyaE, from select box if i select value 2 so i should get 2 tabs if i select value 3 i should get 3 tabs.i hope u got my point

Comment: Hi TommyBS, i dont know how to do it thatsway i am asking ur help..

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
<script>
function getTabs()
{
   var getSelectedValue = $("#week").val();

   if(getSelectedValue == 1)
   {
       //your specified code for value 1
   }
   else if(getSelectedValue == 2)
   {
       //your specified code for value 2
   }
   //and so on.. upto 5 getSelectedValue values
}
</script>

<select id="Week" onchange="getTabs();" name="Week">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a jQuery option.

http://jsfiddle.net/4EjGt/6/

**JS**

```
//Global var to track our selected tabs
var m_selectedTabs = $('#tab1'); 
m_selectedTabs.siblings('span').hide(); 

$('#Week').change(function(){
    SelectTabRangeById($(this).find(':selected').val())
}); 

function SelectTabRangeById(id){
    //Deselect the previous tab 
    m_selectedTabs.hide(); 
    //Find the new Tab
    m_selectedTabs = $('#' + id).prevAll().andSelf();
    //Select it
    m_selectedTabs.show(); 
}

​
```

**HTML**

```
<span id='tab1'>Week 1</span><span id='tab2'>Week 2</span><span id='tab3'>Week 3</span><span id='tab4'>Week 4</span><span id='tab5'>Week 5</span>
<br/>
<select id="Week" name="Week">
    <option value="tab1">1</option>
    <option value="tab2">2</option>
    <option value="tab3">3</option>
    <option value="tab4">4</option>
    <option value="tab5">5</option>
</select>
```

​

Comment: HI Brandon thanks for ur replay but here i want i if i select 2 i want week1 and week2 tabs..if i select 3 i should get week1 week2 and week3 tabs..

Comment: Hi Brandon, this is not i want..by dafault u defined tabs week1 to week5 but if i select 2 i want week1 and week2 remaining tabs shouldnt be visible..